# 'Lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __OSSwapInt16' on jailbroken iPhone when using gem commands

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby, rubygems, jailbreak

I'm having issues with Ruby on iOS 5.1.1. Any `gem` command fails. If I try to `gem update`:

```
mobile$ gem update

Updating installed gems
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __OSSwapInt16 Referenced from: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-darwin9/socket.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __OSSwapInt16
Referenced from: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-darwin9/socket.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What's interesting is `ruby -v` shows 1.9.2:

```
mobile$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [arm-darwin9]
```

Any ideas on how to fix? I've tried removing Ruby package via Cydia and reinstalling but it's the same. I figured this might be relevant for people trying to use gems on their iOS device as I am.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Removing (renaming) socket.bundle unsurprisingly yielded the following results:

```
    ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
        no such file to load -- socket.so
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
        uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::UpdateCommand
```

Edit: I was able to get `gem update` to run successfully by downgrading from ruby 1.9.2-p0-10 to ruby 1.9.1-p429-6. When using 1.9.2, there were still references to 1.9.1 that seem to have been causing the error above.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have since gotten an iPhone 5 and am (obviously) not jailbroken. Perhaps that project will mature a bit in the meantime.

Comment: 1.9.2 is the only version in the repository. By downgrading, what did you do to downgrade? Install ruby manually? From what source?